# Strip out HTML from data-* attribute, leaving New Lines

Tags: html, replace

I've looked around but can't find the answer to this solution.

Is there anyway to strip out HTML tags from a textarea field, leaving line breaks, via data-* attribute?

My code so far: http://jsfiddle.net/xymvcLcv/

I've been able to replace new lines with `<br>`s but unable to work out how to also remove any HTML the user puts in...

`.replace(/\n/g, '<br/>')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To strip html and retrieve only the text, you can use

```js
function stripHTML(html){
  var root = document.implementation.createHTMLDocument().body;
  root.innerHTML = html;
  return root.textContent;
}
```

To preserve new line characters, use [`white-space`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space) CSS property:

```css
white-space: pre; /* preserve newlines, preserve spaces, don't wrap text */
white-space: pre-wrap; /* preserve newlines, preserve spaces, wrap text */
white-space: pre-line; /* preserve newlines, collapse spaces, wrap text */
```

Comment: How would you combine the function so it's in use when the JS is used?

Comment: Ah I get it now! Is there anyway to use data-* as the original code while maintaining the use of the function? Thanks again! Either way you've been a great help

Comment: @potts Yes, I only removed it to simplify. See [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/xymvcLcv/4/)

Comment: I see, what does 'input' do on the forked version: http://jsfiddle.net/uv1o5vyq/ ? If I change input, it breaks?

Comment: @potts [`input`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/input) is an event. Initially, you had `keyup`, but text fields can change in other ways other than typing keys, e.g. with the mouse.

Comment: Thanks Oriol, great answer and great help!

Answer (score 0):

```
.replace(/<[^>]*>/g, '').replace(/<|>/g, '').replace('&', '&amp;').replace(/\n/g, '<br>')
```

It is important to strip the HTML before you add your own.

If you are doing anything but displaying this in their browser after they enter it (ie. storing it in a DB) make sure you sanitize it on the back-end too! Client-side validation is easy to get around.

Comment: This is essentially a 'preview-before-submitting' The backend definitely has all the checks in place :-)